# ASP.Net MVC Postback a label value to your controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When using an EditorTemplate, if I want a value on the model to be displayed on the screen, but also to be posted back to the controller, what helper should I use?

ie. if I use TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
```

...then the user can amend the text...

I would rather just show the text, but if I use:

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
```

...then that is not posted back to the controller.

So is the only way I can display the text, and also to ensure my model state is valid, to add a second hidden field, eg:

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
```

I know that works, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it - so I can display the value, and post it back, without the need to replicate it as a hidden element also?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Using `HiddenFor` is already pretty elegant and standard for these things.

Comment: ok, thanks Steve - I thought MVC/C# may have a "one helper fits all" - but if that's the answer, then please post it, and I'll mark is as such.  Cheers, Mark

Comment: From the looks of it, you might want to reconsider your UI logic. Posting 'everything' (labels included) back to the webserver is very much a WebForms kind of thing. In MVC, it's pretty standard to only post back what's necessary and simply retrieve the values you need from the database/cache. Again, _might_, I don't know your full situation and there might be a valid reason to implement this kind of logic.

Comment: Hi - I'm just trying to show a viewmodel of "offers" - the user has to be able amend those offers, to the price they are happy with, and submit it back.  So I need the descriptions to be posted to the view with the editable price - and for the controller to accept the viewmodel as valid, I need to post back a model which has what I posted to the view (or the model won't be valid when ModelState.IsValid is checked), if that makes sense?? Thanks, Mark

Comment: You may use some CSS to change the look of TextBox to look more like a label (<span>), but it is cleaner using the Hiddens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
```

This is very clean and standard way of doing what you want to achieve.

If you would make your own HTML helper that does exactly the same thing it by saving one line would just confuse other people who might read your code in the future, or even yourself.